# Turning a Hash of Arrays into an Array of Hashes in Ruby

Tags: ruby, arrays, hash

We have the following datastructures:

```
{:a => ["val1", "val2"], :b => ["valb1", "valb2"], ...}
```

And I want to turn that into

```
[{:a => "val1", :b => "valb1"}, {:a => "val2", :b => "valb2"}, ...]
```

And then back into the first form. Anybody with a nice looking implementation?

Comment: did you mean `{:a => ["val1", "val2", ...],  :b => ["valb1", "valb2", ...], ...}`?? so that the output will include, say, `:c => "valc1"`, blah blah blah?

Comment: yeah, we can have :c => ["valc1", "valc2"] too and then the output with have :c => "valc1" for the first object, and :c => "valc2" for th second object... Also, each array may have more than just 2 elements.

Comment: For the Cartesian Product—the result of all possible combinations—see [Calculate all variations for Hash of arrays](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19100525/405017)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This solution works with arbitrary numbers of values (val1, val2...valN):

```
{:a => ["val1", "val2"], :b => ["valb1", "valb2"]}.inject([]){|a, (k,vs)| 
  vs.each_with_index{|v,i| (a[i] ||= {})[k] = v} 
  a
}
# => [{:a=>"val1", :b=>"valb1"}, {:a=>"val2", :b=>"valb2"}]

[{:a=>"val1", :b=>"valb1"}, {:a=>"val2", :b=>"valb2"}].inject({}){|a, h| 
  h.each_pair{|k,v| (a[k] ||= []) << v}
  a
}
# => {:a=>["val1", "val2"], :b=>["valb1", "valb2"]}
```

Comment: W00t! that works :) even with more items in the hash/arrays :) Good work!

Answer (score 8):

Using a functional approach (see Enumerable):

```
hs = h.values.transpose.map { |vs| h.keys.zip(vs).to_h }
#=> [{:a=>"val1", :b=>"valb1"}, {:a=>"val2", :b=>"valb2"}]
```

And back:

```
h_again = hs.first.keys.zip(hs.map(&:values).transpose).to_h
#=> {:a=>["val1", "val2"], :b=>["valb1", "valb2"]}
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's look closely what the data structure we are trying to convert between:

```
#Format A
[
 ["val1", "val2"],          :a
 ["valb1", "valb2"],        :b 
 ["valc1", "valc2"]         :c 
]
#Format B
[ :a        :b       :c
 ["val1", "valb1", "valc1"],
 ["val2", "valb2", "valc3"]
]
```

It is not diffculty to find `Format B` is the transpose of `Format A` in essential , then we can come up with this solution:

```
h={:a => ["vala1", "vala2"], :b => ["valb1", "valb2"], :c => ["valc1", "valc2"]}
sorted_keys =  h.keys.sort_by {|a,b| a.to_s <=> b.to_s}

puts sorted_keys.inject([])  {|s,e| s << h[e]}.transpose.inject([])   {|r, a| r << Hash[*sorted_keys.zip(a).flatten]}.inspect
#[{:b=>"valb1", :c=>"valc1", :a=>"vala1"}, {:b=>"valb2", :c=>"valc2", :a=>"vala2"}]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
m = {}
a,b = Array(h).transpose
b.transpose.map { |y| [a, y].transpose.inject(m) { |m,x| m.merge Hash[*x] }}
```

Answer (score 1):

My attempt, perhaps slightly more compact.

```
h = { :a => ["val1", "val2"], :b => ["valb1", "valb2"] }

h.values.transpose.map { |s| Hash[h.keys.zip(s)] }
```

Should work in Ruby 1.9.3 or later.

---

#### Explanation:

First, 'combine' the corresponding values into 'rows'

```
h.values.transpose
# => [["val1", "valb1"], ["val2", "valb2"]]
```

Each iteration in the `map` block will produce one of these:

```
h.keys.zip(s)
# => [[:a, "val1"], [:b, "valb1"]]
```

and `Hash[]` will turn them into hashes:

```
Hash[h.keys.zip(s)]
# => {:a=>"val1", :b=>"valb1"}      (for each iteration)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `inject` to build an array of hashes.

```
hash = { :a => ["val1", "val2"], :b => ["valb1", "valb2"] }
array = hash.inject([]) do |pairs, pair|
  pairs << { pair[0] => pair[1] }
  pairs
end
array.inspect # => "[{:a=>["val1", "val2"]}, {:b=>["valb1", "valb2"]}]"
```

Ruby documentation has a [few more examples](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Enumerable.html#M003129) of working with `inject`.

Comment: Thanks... but sorry, that didn't work with more items in the hash and arrays.

Answer (score 0):

This will work assuming all the arrays in the original hash are the same size:

```
hash_array = hash.first[1].map { {} }
hash.each do |key,arr|
  hash_array.zip(arr).each {|inner_hash, val| inner_hash[key] = val}
end
```