# How to merge array of hashes to get hash of arrays of values

Tags: ruby, arrays, hash, merge

This is the opposite of [Turning a Hash of Arrays into an Array of Hashes in Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1640979/turning-a-hash-of-arrays-into-an-array-of-hashes-in-ruby).

Elegantly and/or efficiently turn an array of hashes into a hash where the values are arrays of all values:

```
hs = [
  { a:1, b:2 },
  { a:3, c:4 },
  { b:5, d:6 }
]
collect_values( hs )
#=> { :a=>[1,3], :b=>[2,5], :c=>[4], :d=>[6] }
```

This terse code almost works, but fails to create an array when there are no duplicates:

```
def collect_values( hashes )
  hashes.inject({}){ |a,b| a.merge(b){ |_,x,y| [*x,*y] } }
end
collect_values( hs )
#=> { :a=>[1,3], :b=>[2,5], :c=>4, :d=>6 }
```

This code works, but can you write a better version?

```
def collect_values( hashes )
  # Requires Ruby 1.8.7+ for Object#tap
  Hash.new{ |h,k| h[k]=[] }.tap do |result|
    hashes.each{ |h| h.each{ |k,v| result[k]<<v } }
  end
end
```

*Solutions that only work in Ruby 1.9 are acceptable, but should be noted as such.*

---

Here are the results of benchmarking the various answers below (and a few more of my own), using three different arrays of hashes:

- one where each hash has distinct keys, so no merging ever occurs:
  `[{:a=>1}, {:b=>2}, {:c=>3}, {:d=>4}, {:e=>5}, {:f=>6}, {:g=>7}, ...]`
- one where every hash has the same key, so maximum merging occurs:
  `[{:a=>1}, {:a=>2}, {:a=>3}, {:a=>4}, {:a=>5}, {:a=>6}, {:a=>7}, ...]`
- and one that is a mix of unique and shared keys:
  `[{:c=>1}, {:d=>1}, {:c=>2}, {:f=>1}, {:c=>1, :d=>1}, {:h=>1}, {:c=>3}, ...]`

```
               user     system      total        real
Phrogz 2a  0.577000   0.000000   0.577000 (  0.576000)
Phrogz 2b  0.624000   0.000000   0.624000 (  0.620000)
Glenn 1    0.640000   0.000000   0.640000 (  0.641000)
Phrogz 1   0.671000   0.000000   0.671000 (  0.668000)
Michael 1  0.702000   0.000000   0.702000 (  0.700000)
Michael 2  0.717000   0.000000   0.717000 (  0.726000)
Glenn 2    0.765000   0.000000   0.765000 (  0.764000)
fl00r      0.827000   0.000000   0.827000 (  0.836000)
sawa       0.874000   0.000000   0.874000 (  0.868000)
Tokland 1  0.873000   0.000000   0.873000 (  0.876000)
Tokland 2  1.077000   0.000000   1.077000 (  1.073000)
Phrogz 3   2.106000   0.093000   2.199000 (  2.209000)
```

The fastest code is this method that I added:

```
def collect_values(hashes)
  {}.tap{ |r| hashes.each{ |h| h.each{ |k,v| (r[k]||=[]) << v } } }
end
```

I've accepted "[glenn mcdonald's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5490952/merge-array-of-hashes-to-get-hash-of-arrays-of-values/5491741#5491741)" as it was competitive in terms of speed, reasonably terse, but (most importantly) because it pointed out the danger of using a Hash with a self-modifying default proc for convenient construction, as this may introduce bad changes when the user is indexing it later on.

Finally, here's the benchmark code, in case you want to run your own comparisons:

```
require 'prime'   # To generate the third hash
require 'facets'  # For tokland1's map_by
AZSYMBOLS = (:a..:z).to_a
TESTS = {
  '26 Distinct Hashes'   => AZSYMBOLS.zip(1..26).map{|a| Hash[*a] },
  '26 Same-Key Hashes'   => ([:a]*26).zip(1..26).map{|a| Hash[*a] },
  '26 Mixed-Keys Hashes' => (2..27).map do |i|
    factors = i.prime_division.transpose
    Hash[AZSYMBOLS.values_at(*factors.first).zip(factors.last)]
  end
}

def phrogz1(hashes)
  Hash.new{ |h,k| h[k]=[] }.tap do |result|
    hashes.each{ |h| h.each{ |k,v| result[k]<<v } }
  end
end
def phrogz2a(hashes)
  {}.tap{ |r| hashes.each{ |h| h.each{ |k,v| (r[k]||=[]) << v } } }
end
def phrogz2b(hashes)
  hashes.each_with_object({}){ |h,r| h.each{ |k,v| (r[k]||=[]) << v } }
end
def phrogz3(hashes)
  result = hashes.inject({}){ |a,b| a.merge(b){ |_,x,y| [*x,*y] } }
  result.each{ |k,v| result[k] = [v] unless v.is_a? Array }
end
def glenn1(hs)
  hs.reduce({}) {|h,pairs| pairs.each {|k,v| (h[k] ||= []) << v}; h}
end
def glenn2(hs)
  hs.map(&:to_a).flatten(1).reduce({}) {|h,(k,v)| (h[k] ||= []) << v; h}
end
def fl00r(hs)
  h = Hash.new{|h,k| h[k]=[]}
  hs.map(&:to_a).flatten(1).each{|v| h[v[0]] << v[1]}
  h
end
def sawa(a)
  a.map(&:to_a).flatten(1).group_by{|k,v| k}.each_value{|v| v.map!{|k,v| v}}
end
def michael1(hashes)
  h = Hash.new{|h,k| h[k]=[]}
  hashes.each_with_object(h) do |h, result|
    h.each{ |k, v| result[k] << v }
  end
end
def michael2(hashes)
  h = Hash.new{|h,k| h[k]=[]}
  hashes.inject(h) do |result, h|
    h.each{ |k, v| result[k] << v }
    result
  end
end
def tokland1(hs)
  hs.map(&:to_a).flatten(1).map_by{ |k, v| [k, v] }
end
def tokland2(hs)
  Hash[hs.map(&:to_a).flatten(1).group_by(&:first).map{ |k, vs|
    [k, vs.map{|o|o[1]}]
  }]
end

require 'benchmark'
N = 10_000
Benchmark.bm do |x|
  x.report('Phrogz 2a'){ TESTS.each{ |n,h| N.times{ phrogz2a(h) } } }
  x.report('Phrogz 2b'){ TESTS.each{ |n,h| N.times{ phrogz2b(h) } } }
  x.report('Glenn 1  '){ TESTS.each{ |n,h| N.times{ glenn1(h)   } } }
  x.report('Phrogz 1 '){ TESTS.each{ |n,h| N.times{ phrogz1(h)  } } }
  x.report('Michael 1'){ TESTS.each{ |n,h| N.times{ michael1(h) } } }
  x.report('Michael 2'){ TESTS.each{ |n,h| N.times{ michael2(h) } } }
  x.report('Glenn 2  '){ TESTS.each{ |n,h| N.times{ glenn2(h)   } } }
  x.report('fl00r    '){ TESTS.each{ |n,h| N.times{ fl00r(h)    } } }
  x.report('sawa     '){ TESTS.each{ |n,h| N.times{ sawa(h)     } } }
  x.report('Tokland 1'){ TESTS.each{ |n,h| N.times{ tokland1(h) } } }
  x.report('Tokland 2'){ TESTS.each{ |n,h| N.times{ tokland2(h) } } }
  x.report('Phrogz 3 '){ TESTS.each{ |n,h| N.times{ phrogz3(h)  } } }

end
```

Comment: If you needed this functionality, feel free to vote this question up so that others can find it. I asked this and included some working code because (as far as I can tell) there is no good answer for this already on Stack Overflow.

Comment: +1 for an interesting question, alas I couldn't come up with anything nicer than your working solution so far.

Comment: I think each answer should provide a standardized benchmark result too based on your `hs`.

Comment: @theTinMan Ask and you shall receive :)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Take your pick:

```
hs.reduce({}) {|h,pairs| pairs.each {|k,v| (h[k] ||= []) << v}; h}

hs.map(&:to_a).flatten(1).reduce({}) {|h,(k,v)| (h[k] ||= []) << v; h}
```

I'm strongly against messing with the defaults for hashes, as the other suggestions do, because then *checking* for a value modifies the hash, which seems very wrong to me.

Comment: second solution will be mych faster I think

Comment: That's an excellent point that my Hash-with-default_proc is being returned with the default_proc intact, and thus affecting future usage. (Will +1 when I get more votes.)

Comment: In a quick performance test, the second of these is about 1.5x slower than the first. Why did you expect the second one to be faster, fl00r?

Comment: I was trying to think of this myself before I came here. I tried: a.reduce({}) { |acc,k,v|  acc[k]=v; acc } which unfortunately produced this: => {{:a=>"b"}=>nil, {:c=>"d"}=>nil}. Obviously that's not what I wanted. In order to get what is needed, you have to use your solution, which is to run each within the block. Why isn't reduce allowing us to pass the key and value of hash into the second parameter? If it allowed it, then we wouldn't need to use each within the scope of the block.

Comment: Actually, I misunderstood the question here. They wanted values to be an array. No wonder. Otherwise you would just need to do a.reduce(:merge).

Answer (score 3):

```
h = Hash.new{|h,k| h[k]=[]}
hs.map(&:to_a).flatten(1).each{|v| h[v[0]] << v[1]}
```

Answer (score 1):

How's this?

```
def collect_values(hashes)
  h = Hash.new{|h,k| h[k]=[]}
  hashes.each_with_object(h) do |h, result|
    h.each{ |k, v| result[k] << v }
  end
end
```

Edit - Also possible with inject, but IMHO not as nice:

```
def collect_values( hashes )
  h = Hash.new{|h,k| h[k]=[]}
  hashes.inject(h) do |result, h|
    h.each{ |k, v| result[k] << v }
    result
  end
end
```

Comment: Why doesnt `h = Hash.new([])` work? I am getting a `{}` for that.

Comment: @rubyprince That doesn't work because a) it only _returns_ an array when you ask for a non-existent key, but does not _set_ the key to that array, and b) it returns the _same_ array for every key. Run this code in IRB and ponder the output: `h=Hash.new([]); p h[1]; p h; h[:foo] << :a; p h[:bar]; p h`

Comment: I wish I could upvote you twice for reminding me about `each_with_object`. Interestingly, however, using it turns out to be more characters and slower than just using `tap`. (Compare `phrogz2a` and `phrogz2b` methods in the benchmark.)

Answer (score 1):

Same with some other answers using `map(&:to_a).flatten(1)`. The problem is how to modify the values of the hash. I used the fact that arrays are mutable.

```
def collect_values a
  a.map(&:to_a).flatten(1).group_by{|k, v| k}.
  each_value{|v| v.map!{|k, v| v}}
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Facet's [Enumerable#map_by](http://rubyworks.github.com/facets/doc/api/core/Enumerable.html#map-by-method) comes in handy for these cases. This implementation will be no doubt slower than others, but modular and compact code is always easier to maintain:

```
require 'facets'
hs.flat_map(&:to_a).map_by { |k, v| [k, v] }
#=> {:b=>[2, 5], :d=>[6], :c=>[4], :a=>[1, 3]
```

Comment: Where does your `#second` method come from?

Comment: @Phrogz: active_support. I used it just to be concise, write the typical block if AS is not loaded.

Comment: Thanks, I wrote a simple block and benchmarked your answers against the others, and updated the summary in the question.

Answer (score 1):

I thought it might be interesting to compare the winner:

```
def phrogz2a(hashes)
  {}.tap{ |r| hashes.each{ |h| h.each{ |k,v| (r[k]||=[]) << v } } }
end
```

with a slight variant:

```
def phrogz2ai(hashes)
  Hash.new {|h,k| h[k]=[]}.tap {|r| hashes.each {|h| h.each {|k,v| r[k] << v}}}
end
```

because one can often employ either approach (typically to create an empty array or hash).

Using Phrogz's benchmark code, here's how they compare here:

```
            user     system      total        real
Phrogz 2a   0.440000   0.010000   0.450000 (  0.444435)
Phrogz 2ai  0.580000   0.010000   0.590000 (  0.580248)
```

Comment: That _is_ interesting. Thanks for that.

Answer (score 0):

What about this one?

```
hs.reduce({}, :merge)
```

shortest! But performance is pretty bad:

```
       user     system      total        real
 Phrogz 2a  0.240000   0.010000   0.250000 (  0.247337)
 Phrogz 2b  0.280000   0.000000   0.280000 (  0.274985)
 Glenn 1    0.290000   0.000000   0.290000 (  0.290370)
 Phrogz 1   0.310000   0.000000   0.310000 (  0.315548)
 Michael 1  0.360000   0.000000   0.360000 (  0.356760)
 Michael 2  0.360000   0.000000   0.360000 (  0.360119)
 Glenn 2    0.370000   0.000000   0.370000 (  0.369354)
 fl00r      0.390000   0.000000   0.390000 (  0.385883)
 sawa       0.410000   0.000000   0.410000 (  0.408190)
 Tokland 1  0.410000   0.000000   0.410000 (  0.410097)
 Tokland 2  0.490000   0.000000   0.490000 (  0.497325)
 Ich        1.410000   0.000000   1.410000 (  1.413176) # <<-- new
 Phrogz 3   1.760000   0.010000   1.770000 (  1.762979)
```

Comment: It is cute and short, but it fails to produce the correct results. (Read the question to see what those are.) Actual results: `{:a=>3, :b=>5, :c=>4, :d=>6}`.

Answer (score -2):

```
[{'a' => 1}, {'b' => 2}, {'c' => 3}].reduce Hash.new, :merge
```

Comment: While this snippet can help answer the question is better to add a explanation why you think this ill help

Comment: Actually, this snippet does not answer the question. The result it produces is `{:a=>3, :b=>5, :c=>4, :d=>6}` as opposed to the desired `{ :a=>[1,3], :b=>[2,5], :c=>[4], :d=>[6] }`. This is the same as the solution already posted by Ich.