# Group by and format array of hash values in ruby

Tags: ruby, arrays, grouping

Hey I have an array of hash values as follows.

```
[{"group" => "1", "message" => "hey", "weight" => 1}, {"group" => "1", "message" 
 => "hey1", "weight" => 2}, {"group" => "2", "message" => "hey3", "weight" => 4}]
```

I want to group_by group and format it so that I get the following:

```
[{"group" => 1, "messages" => {"hey","hey1"}, "weights" => {1,2}}, {"group" => 2,
  "messages" => {"hey3"}, "weights" => {4}}]
```

Is there a nice ruby way to achieve this?

**Edit**: Now I have:

```
[
  {"group" => "1", "message" => {"hey" => "1"}},
  {"group" => "1", "message" => {"hey1" => "2"}}
]
```

I'd like to have

```
{"group" => "1", "messages" => {"hey1" => "1", "hey2" => "2"} }
```

Comment: You mean `[{"group" => 1, "messages" => ["hey","hey1"], "weights" => [1,2]}`?

Comment: You mean arrays of the messages and weights, right, assuming that they're both ordered the same? Personally, I'd just key off the group, and keep the message and weight as a complete object to avoid any confusion.

Comment: Duplicate of [Merge array of hashes to get hash of arrays of values](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5490952/merge-array-of-hashes-to-get-hash-of-arrays-of-values)

Comment: Yeah I kept msg and weight as own object so now I have the following `[{"group" => "1", "message" => {"hey" => "1"}}, {"group" => "1", "message" => {"hey1" => "2"}}]`  I'd like to have `[{"group" => "1", "messages" => {"hey1" => "1", "hey2" => 2"}]`

Comment: Your needs are rather underspecified. What do you want for `[{a:1},{a:2}]` or `[{a:1},{b:2}]` or `[{a:{b:3}},{a:{b:3}}]` or `[{a:{b:3}},{a:{b:4}}]`?

Answer (score 2):

Based on your revised question:

```
groups = [
  {"group" => "1", "message" => {"hey" => "1"}},
  {"group" => "1", "message" => {"hey1" => "2"}}
]

merged = groups.inject do |h1,h2|
  h1.merge(h2) do |k,v1,v2|
    if v1==v2
      v1
    elsif v1.is_a?(Hash) && v2.is_a?(Hash)
      v1.merge(v2)
    else
      [*v1,*v2]
    end
  end
end

p merged
#=> {"group"=>"1", "message"=>{"hey"=>"1", "hey1"=>"2"}}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the output you want is:

```
[{"messages"=>["hey", "hey1"], "weights"=>[1, 2], "group"=>"1"}, {"messages"=>["hey3"], "weights"=>[4], "group"=>"2"}]
```

If this is the case, this code does what you want:

```
h.group_by { |item| item["group"] }.values.map do |item|
    item.inject({"messages" => [], "weights" => []}) do |result, subitem|
        result["group"] = subitem["group"]
        result["messages"] << subitem["message"]
        result["weights"] << subitem["weight"]
        result
    end
end
```

You should be able to improve it knowing more about your specific problem, but it should be a good starting point.