# Get an array of the values of a key from an array of hashes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays

For an array like this:

```
 a = [{a:'a',b:'3'},{a:'b',b:'2'},{a:'c',b:'1'}]
```

I would like to return an array containing values for `:a` keys, so:

```
 ['a', 'b', 'c']
```

That can be done using:

```
 a.map{|x|x[:a]}
```

I wonder if there is a native method in Rails or Ruby to do it like this?

```
 a.something :a
```

Comment: I'd say the map function is about as concise as you are going to get it.

Comment: yes but not as readable... =( i found this work with array of rails models... results.collect(&:key_name) but not with hashes.

Comment: FYI #collect and #map are the same thing.  The reason that second one does not work is that the syntax you used calls send with key_name as a an argument, not calling [] as you are thinking.  I prefer map. Using Enumerable maps is very readable and it is one of the functions I use most as a Ruby programmer.

Comment: You need to use `#map`, that has to be go that way.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can do it yourself:

```
class Array
  def get_values(key)
    self.map{|x| x[key]}
  end
end
```

Then you can do this:

```
a.get_values :a
#=> ["a", "b", "c"]
```

Comment: `get_keys` is a misnomer. You're returning the values, not the keys.

Comment: You're right of course. Not sure what I was thinking. Updated.

Comment: I probably would not do that though I think this is less readable than  simply using map. Opening Array is kinda evil and anything you name this function will not describe what it does better than looking at map.  But I suppose the OP did ask for a method to do it!

Answer (score 1):

More than you need in this case, but from [How to merge array of hashes to get hash of arrays of values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5490952/merge-array-of-hashes-to-get-hash-of-arrays-of-values) you can get them all at once:

```
merged = a.inject{ |h1,h2| h1.merge(h2){ |_,v1,v2| [*v1,*v2] } }
p merged[:a] #=> ["a", "b", "c"]
p merged[:b] #=> ["3", "2", "1"]
```

Also, if you use something like Struct or OpenStruct for your values instead of hashes—or any object that allows you to get the "a" values as a method that does not require parameters—you can use the `Symbol#to_proc` convenience for your map:

```
AB = Struct.new(:a,:b)
all = [ AB.new('a','3'), AB.new('b','2'), AB.new('c','1') ]
#=> [#<AB a="a", b="3">, #<AB a="b", b="2">, #<AB a="c", b="1">]

all.map(&:a) #=> ["a", "b", "c"]
all.map(&:b) #=> ["3", "2", "1"]
```