# Merge two Hashes and group them by the key

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, hash, grouping

I'm trying to merge two Hashes into one Array in such a way that is possible to show them in a table like this:

[image]

for now I'm only able to arrange the Array to have this format:
[{"Motivation"=>4, "Leadership"=>3, "Innovation"=>1}, {"Leadership"=>2, "Motivation"=>3, "Innovation"=>1}]

In my Model I have this code:

```
  def rates_table_index

  total = []

  ...
  ...
  slf_cc = ...

  self_cc = {}

  slf_cc.each do |cc|
    self_cc[cc.title] = cc.rate
  end

  total << self_cc

  other_cc = {}

  other_ccs = ...

  other_ccs.each do |cc|
    other_cc[cc.title] = cc.rate
  end

  total << other_cc

  result = total

end
```

The Title and the rate are an input from the user so I don't know how to group the values by there keys.

in my view I've got this:

```
<h2>Table</h2>
<table class="table">
  <thead>
  <tr>
    <th>Column 1</th>
    <th>Column 2</th>
    <th>Column 3</th>
  </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>

  <% @model.rates_table_index.each do |title, values| %>
          <tr>
            <td><%= title %></td>
            <td><%= values[0] %></td>
            <td><%= values[1] %></td>
          </tr>
      <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Can anyone help me please?

Comment: Will both the entries always have the same length of keys?

Comment: yes, both entries have the same length of keys, only the number of values can vary for each key.

Comment: I am sorry I don't get you. "the number of values can vary for each key." ?

Comment: sorry for the poor anwser, yes, both entries have the same length of keys, ignore the " the number of values can vary for each key"

Comment: Try my solution and let me know if it works.

Comment: @Arun, now i get this format in the array: [{"BUSINESS FOCUS"=>[4, 3]}, {"COMMUNICATION"=>[3, 2]}, {"INNOVATION"=>[1, 1]}], this is exacly what i wanted but i can't display it properly in the view, i updated my question with the new code

Comment: i updated my question with the code you provided in your anwser, i'm getting an undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass error in the line with the values[0]

Comment: My bad. I was wrong. I have updated my answer. Please try it and let me know if it works.

Comment: rates_table_index returns the rates array [{"BUSINESS FOCUS"=>[4, 3]}, {"COMMUNICATION"=>[3, 2]}, {"INNOVATION"=>[1, 1]}]

Comment: You don't need an array of hashes. Please try my updated answer.

Comment: it worked like a charm!!!!! many thanks!!!!

Comment: Glad it worked! Sorry for confusing you initially.

Comment: no problem, i also confuse you with the first comment!thank you once again! cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a hash with title('Motivation', 'Leadership' etc) as the keys and array(`[4,3]`, `[3,2]` etc) as the values.

```
# self_cc = {"Motivation"=>4, "Leadership"=>3, "Innovation"=>1}
# other_cc = {"Leadership"=>2, "Motivation"=>3, "Innovation"=>1}

rates = {}

keys = self_cc.keys
keys.each do |k|
  rates[k] = [self_cc[k], other_cc[k]]
end

# rates
# => {"Motivation"=>[4, 3], "Leadership"=>[3, 2], "Innovation"=>[1, 1]}
```

Display the data by iterating over the hash in the view.

```
<% rates.each do |title, values| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= title %></td>
    <td><%= values[0] %></td>
    <td><%= values[1] %></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
```

Comment: One more thing, who should i do if i get a variable number of values. I mean, in this case, i'm only adding two values for each key, so i could add directly the self value from the self_cc and the other from the other_cc, but if the number of values varies who could i do that?

Comment: just the model part

Answer (score 0):

This has been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5490952/how-to-merge-array-of-hashes-to-get-hash-of-arrays-of-values):

Rephrasing the same in your question's context, looks like this:

```
[self_cc, other_cc].reduce({}) {|h,pairs| pairs.each {|k,v| (h[k] ||= []) << v}; h}
```